# Force IE8 compatibility mode off for Intranet site using meta tags

Tags: jsf, intranet, ie8-compatibility-mode

All of the following questions are related and some of them marked as fix but does not seem to be working.

My problem:

1. Problem with IE8.
2. I have Intranet site built on Primefaces 5.1.7,
   JSF 2.2.8-04
3. Trying to disable compatibility mode of IE8 which is
   enabled by default for Intranet web sites.
4. Problem is we want to set minimum browser requirement to IE8, but web side is run on Intranet domain so it by default runs on compatibility mode and IE8 user is not allowed to login.

Solution Available (Not working):

```
<f:facet name="first">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</f:facet>
```

Following does not work:

1. [Force IE compatibility mode off using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449286/force-ie-compatibility-mode-off-in-ie-using-tags#comment26890406_3449338)
2. [Force "Internet Explorer 8" browser mode in intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742853/force-internet-explorer-8-browser-mode-in-intranet)
3. [X-UA-Compatible not working in IE 9 for intranet sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571231/x-ua-compatible-not-working-in-ie-9-for-intranet-sites)
4. [intranet jsf application opening in compatibility mode in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144153/intranet-jsf-application-opening-in-compatibility-mode-in-ie9)
5. [How to fix Document mode restart in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095319/how-to-fix-document-mode-restart-in-ie-9)

Any help is appreciated.

**First Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-bluesky" />
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/css/screen.css.jsf" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1.7"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1.7"></script>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1.7" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.1.7"></script>
                <title>Payroll Center</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/payroll/javax.faces.resource/js/script.js.jsf"></script><!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/payroll/resources/js/selectivizr-min.js"></script><![endif]-->
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/payroll/resources/img/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

**Second Edit:**

1. Screenshot is from IE developer tool.
2. I removed that xml tag
3. There are two things in tool Browser mode and Document Mode.
4. Document Mode is getting changed to IE8 Standards but Browser mode remains the same, Browser mode is the key to change version which does not gets changed.
5. I might me wrong i am just guessing for now that document mode gives ability to run some IE8 features but still running under IE8 compatibility mode which is basicall version IE7. NOT SURE GUESS

[image]

[image]

**Third Edit**:

As per following blog you can not change browser mode but this was written in 2010. i am no sure how much valid this is but what he explains actually happening. But require second opinion if this is really true. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx

Thanks again for your time

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144153/intranet-jsf-application-opening-in-compatibility-mode-in-ie9